# Люди з особливими потребами VS люди з інвалідністю?

Tags: терміни, словосполучення, стилістика

Читаю ці два варіанти на різних сайтах, зокрема:

1. [Сredo.pro](http://credo.pro/2018/03/203732):

   > **Люди з особливими потребами**, зокрема з синдромом Дауна, допомагають нам долати бар’єри, які ми самі навколо себе будуємо.
2. [Міжнародний благодійний фонд "Волонтерське об’єднання" "Крила"](http://kryla.org.ua/mova-i-etyket/):

   > **Люди з інвалідністю:** мова і етикет.

Так, знаю, що Петро Порошенко підписав закон №2249-VII, згідно з яким із законодавства вилучається термін *інвалід* та *особа з обмеженими фізичними можливостями* і впроваджується термін особа з інвалідністю. Джерело: [Українська правда](https://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2018/01/16/7168530/).

Однак про вживання словосполучення люди з особливими потребами нічого не вказано.

Отже, то як коректніше вживати термін?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Досить зрозумілу, обгрунтовану позицію знайшла у статті [Людина з інвалідністю чи з особливими потребами?](http://pcholkin.com/lyudyna-z-invalidnistyu-chy-z-osoblyvymy-potrebamy/)

> КМЦСССДМ пропонує використовувати «слова та поняття, які не створюють стереотипів» [...]
>   Та вже саме використання слова **ОБМЕЖЕНИЙ** і є стереотипом. Конвенція ООН про права осіб з інвалідністю говорить: «Комітет бере до уваги запит Держави-учасниці стосовно термінології на позначення осіб з інвалідністю і вважає, що використання термінології українською мовою, яка називає осіб з інвалідністю «інвалідами» або «особами з обмеженими фізичними можливостями», не відповідає Конвенції».
>
> Як відомо, згідно сучасної соціальної моделі інвалідності – інвалідність не є проблемою певної людини, адже вона настає через непереборні фізичні бар’єри в навколишньому середовищі, відсутність можливості рівного доступу до інформації, освіти в школах і вузах, працевлаштування, житла тощо, тобто це проблема суспільства.
>   Саме тому, **НЕ РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО** вживати термін «**людина з обмеженими можливостями»** **(особливими потребами)**,натомість на його місце без проблем сідає «**людина з інвалідністю»** – більш ніж чітко і зрозуміло.

На [ЕнергоЛайф. інфо](http://energolife.info/ua/2017/Society/4445/%C2%AB%D0%86%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B7-%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%C2%BB-%E2%80%93-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83.htm) також знаходимо інформацію, що замість **люди з особливими потребами** потрібно вживати **люди з інвалідністю**.

Ту саму інформацію бачимо в інтерв'ю у [Сніданок з 1+1](https://1plus1.ua/tsn/novyny/ak-pravilno-nazivati-ludej-z-invalidnistu).

Отже, коректніше вживати  **люди з інвалідністю**, а різне вживання термінів у просторах інтернету, пояснюється необізнаністю журналістів, блогерів і т.д.